# So much water in cake, how to fix?

Tags: cake

My [mango chantilly cake](http://test.www.goldilocks.com.ph/products/bakeshop/new-products/mango-chantilly-cake/370) has fallen, due to too much water inside the plastic [storage](http://www.rubbermaid.com/Category/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?CatName=FoodStorage&Prod_ID=RP091259&Redirect=1). Now, assuming that I don't have an oven what are the practical workarounds that I can try to fix the cake?

So far this are the things that I did:

1. Removed all the water, but still the cake is watery and not good looking.
2. I tried to put it in a rice cooker then while trying to pre-heat the rice I put the cake in a steamer then put it in the rice cooker, but it's still damp/soggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a stove: Put a pan on the stove and use low heat to "toast" your cake.
If you only have a rice cooker: The rice cooker is only for "wet-cooking" like cooking rice or steaming. I don't know whether toasting food in the rice cooker breaks the cooker. Therefore I don't know how to fix the cake then.  :(

Comment: It is okay, at least we can have a way for fixing messed up cakes. :) Thanks a lot Ching Chong!